# CURL JSON REQUEST AS GET

Tags: php, json, curl

**[example.com URL](https://example.com/price?callback=jsonCallback&brand=TOYOTA&model=COROLLA%201.6&gender=Male&md_age=58&marital_status=Married&car_age=7&ncd=0.1&data=%7B%0A%20%20%22car_data%22:%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22make%22:%20%22TOYOTA%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22model%22:%20%22COROLLA%201.6%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22year_of_manufacture%22:%20%222006%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22offpeak%22:%20%22yes%22%0A%20%20%7D,%0A%20%20%22drivers_data%22:%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22driver_1%22:%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22gender%22:%20%22Male%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22marital_status%22:%20%22Married%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22date_of_birth%22:%20%2223/5/1954%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22year_driving_license%22:%20%221981%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ncd%22:%20%220.1%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22occupation%22:%20%22ZFOR:%20Forex%20Trader/Broker%20/%20Remiser%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22relationship%22:%20%22%20%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D,%0A%20%20%22discount_data%22:%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22certificate_of_merit%22:%20null%0A%20%20%7D,%0A%20%20%22claims_data%22:%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22have_claims%22:%20%22no%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22claims_number%22:%20%220%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22claims_amount%22:%20%220%22%0A%20%20%7D,%0A%20%20%22product_data%22:%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22plan%22:%20null,%0A%20%20%20%20%22price%22:%20null,%0A%20%20%20%20%22policy_start%22:%20%2218/5/2013%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22policy_end%22:%20%2217/5/2014%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22ncd%22:%20false,%0A%20%20%20%20%22excess%22:%20null%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&_=1368821334250)**

I am calling this url but getting `jsonCallback({"ERROR": "6"});`. I cannot understand what this is. I have searched many times for the error but could not find out anything helpful.

This is a website by calling this url I will get price list. When I am calling this from the website itself I am getting the data properly. but whenever I a m going to copy the http request and paste it to url it is showing error.

Below are my CURL request :

```
<?php

   class CURL {
   var $callback = false;

function setCallback($func_name) {
    $this->callback = $func_name;
}

function doRequest($method, $url, $vars) {
    $headers=array();
    $headerVar=0;
    $headers[$headerVar]='Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8';    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    if ($method == 'POST') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
    }
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo '<br><br>'.curl_error().'-----'.curl_error();
    return $data;

    if ($data) {
        if ($this->callback)
        {
            $callback = $this->callback;
            $this->callback = false;
            return call_user_func($callback, $data);
        } else {
            return $data;
        }
    } else {
        return curl_error($ch);
    }
}

function get($url) {
    return $this->doRequest('GET', $url, 'NULL');
}

function post($url, $vars) {
    return $this->doRequest('POST', $url, $vars);
}
  }


      function stringParameter($array)  {
    $post_items=array();
    foreach ( $array as $key => $value) {
        $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
    }
    //create the final string to be posted using implode()
    $post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);
    return $post_string;
      }

     function build_http_query( $query ){

    $query_array = array();

    foreach( $query as $key => $key_value ){


        if($key_value != ''){
            $query_array[] = urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode( $key_value );
        }else {
            $query_array[] = urlencode($key) . '=' .  $key_value ;
        }
    }

    return htmlspecialchars(implode( '&', $query_array ));

     }

        list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime()); 
      $time13 = sprintf('%d%03d', $sec, $usec/1000); 

       $data    =   
    array(
        "brand" => "PERODUA",
        "model" => "VIVA 1.0",
        "gender" => "Male",
        "md_age" => '35',
        "marital_status" => "Married",
        "car_age" => '8',
        "ncd" => '0',
        "data" => 
                        array(
                        "car_data" => array( 
                                                           "make"=>"PERODUA", 
                                        "model"=>"VIVA 1.0", 
                                        "year_of_manufacture"=>"2004", 
                                        "offpeak"=>"yes"    
                                    ),
                        "drivers_data" => array( 
                                        "driver_1"=>    array(
                                                "gender"                => "Male",
                                                "marital_status"        => "Married",
                                                "date_of_birth"         => "22/3/1978",
                                                "year_driving_license"  => "1999",
                                                "ncd"                   => "0",
                                                "occupation"            => "ZADM: Indoor Office/Exec/Admin Staff",
                                                "relationship"          => " "
                                        )       
                                    ),
                        "discount_data" => array(
                                        "certificate_of_merit" => false
                                    ),
                        "claims_data" => array(
                                        "have_claims"   => "no",
                                        "claims_number" => "0",
                                        "claims_amount" => "0"
                                    ),
                        "product_data" =>  array(
                                        "plan"  => null,
                                        "price" => null,
                                        "policy_start"=> "1/5/2013",
                                        "policy_end"=> "30/4/2014",
                                            "ncd"=> false,
                                             "excess"=> null
                                    )                       
                        ) 
        );              

   $encode = build_http_query($data);
$url = 'https://example.com/price?callback=jsonCallback&'.$encode;  
$obj = new CURL();
echo $ppp =  $obj->get($url);


 ?>
```

Am I am wrong in sending the data in the url as it is written in json?

Answer (score 0):

The {"ERROR": "6"} message is a custom error message return by https://axasingaporemotor.appspot.com/price

You will need to contact the owner of that URL in order to understand what they mean by error 6.

Comment: This is the real url:https://axasingaporemotor.appspot.com/price?callback=jsonCallback&'.$encode; Please do something.

Comment: do you own the server side's code (those on axa...appspot.com) - which is running App Engine.

It's up to that code to return whatever error message to you and it's within their domain for debugging the problem. (since error 6 is defined by them and not something the public will understand). Without access the source code you can only contact their owner for help.

I'll edit my answer~

Comment: I know that but please review my urlencode. Does it have any kind of error in sending to that url ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `build_http_query` but `http_build_query` instead